# Implementing Log in form in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I'm trying to make Log in window in my application, I'm pretty new to WPF and it's not going so well for me.

This is what I did, and I'm not even sure is this correct way, but anyway my question is described in code comments.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window_LogInScreen loginScreen = new Window_LogInScreen();
        loginScreen.ShowDialog();

        if (loginScreen.DialogResult == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login success I should keep executing my application.."); // how could I continue my application if this condition is allright?
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login failed"); //how could I stop my application if I reach this code, and how to stay on LogIn_Screen form so user can enter password again..
        }

        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }


}
```

My Window_LogInScreen :

```
public partial class Window_LogInScreen : Window
{
    public Window_LogInScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblPasswordBox.Focus();
    }


    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (lblPasswordBox.Password == "1")//lets say pw is "1" for testing purposes
            {
                this.DialogResult = true;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
                this.DialogResult = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So guys how could I achieve that?

In window forms I would do  this is Program.cs, but in WPF I'm somehow lost and I don't know how to achieve this on a right way,

but my logic is:

> 1) open LogIn screen before application run, check for password when
>   user press Enter on keyboard, if password is OK then set DialogResult
>   to true,
>
> 2) go back to `MainWindow`, check there is `DialogResult==true`, if
>   yes, then keep going with execution of `MainWindow`, else, stop
>   application and stay on `LogIn_Screen` so user can enter password
>   again..

Thanks guys,
Cheers

EDIT after Xioy312 answer:

@Xiaoy312 The code you posted is really awesome, and I'm really intrested in this code, but it looks a bit incomprehensible to me..

Let's back to your first EDIT,

```
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter && lblPasswordBox.Password == "1")
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
```

how come `this.DialogResult` will not
become false if condition is not satisfied? because with that code that you have posted in your answer before last edit,  `MessageBox.Show("login failed");` from `Application_Startup` would never be reached, and I'm wondering why?
I guess if mentioned condtion (`if (e.Key == Key.Enter && lblPasswordBox.Password == "1")`) is not satisfied, than DialogResult will be false and `MessageBox.Show("login failed");` 
from else part would be called? but actualy that is not true, because here we have that failed attempt is silent, and I'm wondering why?

And also, how come application would exit with this Behavior? Can you explain little bit what's happening behind, as much as I can se you'r assigning value to a DialogResult in case it is "1".. ?

```
#region Behavior 1: Exit the application on invalid password
        this.DialogResult = lblPasswordBox.Password == "1";
        this.Close();
        #endregion
```

Could you explain this code little bit, I would be so  thankful!

Comment: In my first edit, the dialog result is only set when the enter key is press AND with the correct password. Furthermore, the login window is never closed when an invalid password is entered, *so the user can have chance to re-enter it*.

Comment: In `Behavior 1`, we are **not** "assigning value to `DialogResult` in case it is '1'". Instead, `DialogResult` is given the result of whether **the password is correct**. If it is correct, `DialogResult` will be `true`. If not, it will be `false`.

Comment: Maybe you can understand it better if I wrote it this way: `this.DialogResult = (lblPasswordBox.Password == "1");`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Now it is much more understandable, In your first edit  dialog result is only set when the enter key is press AND with the correct password AND ONLY IN THAT CASE `DialogResult` will be set to true, but I tought: if that condition is not satisfied, than `DialogResult` will be set to something else ( thought about false )... so in fact `DialogResult` will not be set to anything else until we say it. i.e. `DialogResult=false;`, am I correct? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: If a condition is not met, anything within the `if`-block not simply not be executed. Therefore, `DialogResult` will remain the same. In this case, it will be the default value of `bool?` which is `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to lock the users out of the application unless they are authenticated, you can define a startup routine instead of opening the `MainWindow` directly.

In `App.xaml`, remove the `StartupUri` property and add these two instead:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
</Application>
```

*`OnExplicitShutdown` is there to prevent the application from shutting down after we are done with the login window.*

In `App.xaml.cs`, you should find the event handler `Application_Startup` where you can dictate the flow of the application:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (new LoginWindow().ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login success I should keep executing my application..");
            new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("login failed");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Shutdown();
    }
}
```

EDIT: The login logic should be contained within the `LoginWindow`, and should not be leaked into the `Application` or `MainWindow`:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // lets say pw is "1" for testing purposes
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && lblPasswordBox.Password == "1")
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you don't like the invalid password to fail silently, you can change this behavior in `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
private void LoginWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // You should keep only one of two:
        #region Behavior 1: Exit the application on invalid password
        this.DialogResult = lblPasswordBox.Password == "1";
        this.Close();
        #endregion
        #region Behavior 2: Warn the user on invalid password
        if (lblPasswordBox.Password == "1")
        {
            this.DialogResult = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("invalid password");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok buddy, I will try this soon, and about Application_Startup event, well why is that ShutDown method contained in finally block? It means that method will be executed and I'm wondering why?

Comment: The reason `Shutdown()` is wrapped into a try-finally is to prevent a ghost application hanging in the void if `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` was handled. In general, you can just leave out the try-finally block if you arn't messing with `App.Current.DUE...`.

Comment: as soon as I try this I will leave you a comment and mark your answer as ANSWER :) Thanks man

Comment: How come this: MessageBox.Show("login failed"); from private void Application_Startup method is never reached if I enter incorect passwords? If i enter password different than 1 shouldn't my LoginWindow dialog be false and MessageBox should be executed? Instead of that it keeps LoginWindow opened while password is incorect.. Thanks

Comment: @Roxy'Pro The idea is to allow user to enter the password multiple times if they have it wrong. And, an failed attempt is silent. You can, however, change this behavior in `PreviewKeyDown`. Check my edit to see what I mean.

Comment: could you check for EDIT I made on question, code is great, but I'm little bit confused, so please take a look at my EDIT mate, I would be very thanful! :)

Comment: will the try/catch in the startup make the application catch any and all errors from MainWindow? it seems like it will, would make unexpected errors in production easier to log out.